# java get only one prime number randomly

Tags: java, primes

I'm trying to figure out how to take a prime number randomly.

I mean, the result must be one prime number only.

I already created a method `checkPrime(int a, int b)` to check whether the number is prime or not.

Then, I loop from `0` to `256` and search for prime numbers.

After that, I must get one of those prime numbers randomly.

From my part of code below, it printed result: `2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47`

```
    System.out.println("Prime number: ");
    for(int a = 0; a < 256; a++){  
        boolean checkIt = checkPrime(a, 5); //check whether the number is prime or not
        if(checkIt){
            System.out.print(a + " "); 
        }  
    }
```

Result I expected is only one prime number. It might 3 or 43 or 17 or 31 or etc.

What must I do to solve this?

Comment: You must make it stop after finding one prime number...

Comment: Start at a random number and search from there. However, this will make prime numbers that follow a large gap more likely than others.

Comment: Put it in the array, gernerate with Random an int and use it as index.

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the execution of a loop if you like; so you would do something like this:

```
System.out.println("Prime number: ");
for(int a = 0; a < 256; a++){  
    boolean checkIt = checkPrime(a, 5); //check whether the number is prime or not
    if(checkIt){
        System.out.print(a + " "); 
        break;
    }  
}
```

That way once your loop has found its first prime number it will abort the calculation.

**EDIT:** To add a random element you'll have to choose the numbers you check randomly or choose where to stop randomly. One example could be this:

```
System.out.println("Prime number: ");
Ramdom rand = new Random();
for(int a = 0; a < 256; a++){  
    int check = random.nextInt();
    boolean checkIt = checkPrime(check, 5); //check whether the number is prime or not
    if(checkIt){
        System.out.print(check + " "); 
        break;
    }  
}
```

This will check up to 256 random numbers. If you want to make sure you'll find one, I'd suggest something like this:

```
System.out.println("Prime number: ");
Ramdom rand = new Random();
int prime;
do {  
    prime = rand.nextInt();
} while(!checkPrime(prime, 5));
System.out.print(prime + " ");
```

Comment: This should always print 2, which does not really look like random (although we never can't be sure)

Comment: Hey, I chose 2 by random. ;-) But seriously, if you want to choose a number randomly you'll have to add some random element.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind True. I've edited my answer to find random values.

Answer (score 1):

You can for example put each prime number in a table and then randomly take one element from that table.

```
Random generator = new Random();
List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
System.out.println("Prime number: ");
     for(int a = 0; a < 256; a++){  
          if(checkPrime(a, 5)){
                primes.add(a);
          }  
     }
System.out.print(primes.get(generator.nextInt(primes.size())));
```

Be careful, I did not test it ;)

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the same solution only with array or different data structure (it is up to him what he prefers to use)

Comment: I post answer check out

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below :

Store all prime number in arraylist and then shuffle it or get random index.

```
ArrayList<Integer>  lista = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int a = 0; a < 256; a++){  
            boolean checkIt = checkPrime(a, 5); //check whether the number is prime or not
            if(checkIt){
                lista.add(a);
            }  
        }

Collections.shuffle(lista);
System.out.println(lista.get(0));


 // or

Random r = new Random();
int index = r.nextInt(lista.size()); 

Integer RandPrimeNum = lista.get(index);
 System.out.println(""+RandPrimeNum);
```

Comment: While this gives a correct result, it is not the most efficient way to select a random element.

Comment: @Henry totally agreed. Shuffling the whole list just to pick one random number is kinda overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

1. Store prime numbers retrived in loop in `ArrayList<Integer>`
2. Get the size of arraylist and use `random` function to access number from that array list

for example. Say `ArrayList` size is 10 than use Random function to generate random number between 0 to 9 so what ever number you get use that number to access arrayList element.

Answer (score 0):

You can you an Array where to put you Prime numbers.
Then you choose randomly an index from the array.

```
int[] array = new int[100];
int i = 0 ;
    System.out.println("Prime number: ");
    for(int a = 0; a < 256; a++){  
        boolean checkIt = checkPrime(a, 5); //check whether the number is prime or not
        if(checkIt){
            array[i] = a ;
            i++;
        }  
    }
int minimum = 0 ;
int maximum = array.length();
int randomNum = minimum  + (int)(Math.random()*maximum); 
System.out.println(array[randomNum]);
```

Comment: If you get more than 100 primes, this fails. You're not supposed to know in advance how many primes you will find, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the down vote, but if you didn't see he loops to **256** so  he know in advance how many number will check if it's prime.
if the **100** was a problem we can change it to a dynamic Array. and please flag this comment too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

Create a list to store the prime numbers:

```
ArrayList<Integer> primeNums = new ArrayList<>();
```

Store each prime in the list:

```
System.out.println("Prime number: ");
for(int a = 0; a < 256; a++){  
    if(checkPrime(a, 5)){
        primeNums.add(a);
    }  
}
```

Choose a random index in the list's range:

```
Random r = new Random();
int randomIndex = r.nextInt(primeNums.size());
```

Pick the prime number:

```
Integer myRandomPrime = primeNums.get(randomIndex);
```

Comment: Downvoter, please care to comment what is wrong with my solution. I'll be glad to improve it.

Comment: @Alaeddine This is not a mistake, but a Java 7 feature. Your "corrected" version would even generate a redundancy warning in eclipse. You can take a look here for more info about the diamond operator http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074080/core-java/jdk-7--the-diamond-operator.html

Answer (score 0):

First, Insert Prime Numbers :

```
for(int a = 0; a < 256; a++){  
        boolean checkIt = checkPrime(a, 5); //check whether the number is prime or not
        if(checkIt){
          PrimeNumebrArray.add(a); //PrimeNumebrArray is array list object
          arraySize++; //array index counter, initialized at 0 
        }  
    }
```

Now, Generate random Number

```
int index = Math.random() * arraySize;
```

This would return a value in the range [0,arraySize].

```
int PrimeNumebr = PrimeNumebrArray.get(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this?

```
public int getPrime() {
  List<Integer> primes = getPrimes();
  int idx = System.currentTimeMillis() % primes.size();
  return primes.get(idx);
}

private List<Integer> getPrimes() {
  List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int a = 0; a < 256; a++){  
    boolean checkIt = checkPrime(a, 5); //check whether the number is prime or not
      if(checkIt){
        primes.add(a);
      }  
    }
  }
}
```

It's not very robust, however might be enough depending on your use case.